# How to Enable Inherent Permission of an OU to All Users via Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Some of the members in an OU have the inheritance disabled. How can I do that in Powershell?  This is the GUI window if it helps what I am trying to ask...
[image]

Comment: An OU doesn't have "members". I you talking about objects contained in an OU, or the OU itself? (maybe it's easier if you simply describe what you would do in the GUI to accomplish what you're after)

Comment: It is most likely that those users' inheritance is disabled because they are a member of one or more administrative groups. To see if this is true, look at one such user object and look for the presence of the AdminCount property.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675212(v=vs.85).aspx
You may not be able to set (and retain) inheritance on users that are members of certain built-in administrative groups unless they are removed from such groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automate that button on your screenshot, here's a code, [from there](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/muaddib/2013/12/30/how-to-modify-security-inheritance-on-active-directory-objects-using-powershell/):

```
Function Set-Inheritance { 
    param($ObjectPath) 
    $ACL = Get-ACL -path "AD:\$ObjectPath"
    If( $acl.AreAccessRulesProtected ){ 
        $ACL.SetAccessRuleProtection( $False, $True )
        Set-ACL -AclObject $ACL -path "AD:\$ObjectPath"
        Write-Host "MODIFIED "$ObjectPath
    } #End IF 
 } #End Function Set-Inheritance
```